# Template 10: Hamburger Menu can not auto open after changing VisualStateDisplayMode

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, template10, hamburger-menu

I'm a little puzzled on Hamburger Menu 's DisplayMode. 
I want the hamburger menu can be completely closed in Normal and wide visual states.
I try to set `VisualStateWideDisplayMode` to `Inline`,it's Indeed inline but the pane cannot open automaticaly.when i open the pane and click navigate to another page,the pane closed.but I want it can be always open.
I try to set `IsOpen` to True,but i's no effect.

If i should write some triggers or use another way? 
Thanks for help.

code like this:

```
     <Controls:HamburgerMenu x:Name="MyHamburgerMenu" 
                             VisualStateNormalDisplayMode="Overlay"
                             VisualStateWideDisplayMode="Inline"
                             IsOpen="True"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have checked the source code of [Template10](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/). It seems that it's by design. Even if you have set the DisplayMode and IsOpen value on xaml page. But in HamburgerMenu's code-behind, it always would change DisplayMode and IsOpen's value according to the VisualStateGroup.CurrentState's value. 
You could see this behavior in "[UpdateVisualStates()](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/blob/master/Template10%20(Library)/Controls/HamburgerMenu.xaml.cs#L618)" method in Template10 source code.

So I think if you want change this default behavior, you need to rebuild a custom version yourself. Or you could use SplitView to make your custom HamburgerMenu control like James Quick descirbes here: [Windows 10 SplitView – Build Your First Hamburger Menu](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/quick_thoughts/2015/06/01/windows-10-splitview-build-your-first-hamburger-menu/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer,I'll try it

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have discovered a bug. I have reported it here https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/issues/1381

Thank you for using Template 10